# Move an ImageView to different a position using animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have several ImageViews in a RelativeLayout.

When the user taps any of the ImageViews, I want the ImageView to be moved to a specified location using a subtle animation.

Eg; I have initially set margins for `LayoutParams` associated with an `ImageView` as `layoutparams1.setMargins(90,70,0,0);` and I have then added it to the layout.

When the ImageView is tapped, I'd like its new location to be `200,200`, done with animation.

So, is it possible? if yes, then how?

Note that I have both RelativeLayout and all of its child ImageViews created programmatically.

And I'm new to Android development so an elaborative answer is expected.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 50, 0, 100);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(false);
animation.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener());

imageView.startAnimation(animation);
```

**UPDATE :**
The problem is that the `View` is actually still in it's old position. So we have to move it when the animation is finished. To detect when the animation is finished we have to create our own `animationListener` (inside our `activity` class):

```
private class MyAnimationListener implements AnimationListener{

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        imageView.clearAnimation();
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
        lp.setMargins(50, 100, 0, 0);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

}
```

So the `onClickEvent` will get fired again at it's new place.
The animation will now move it even more down, so you might want to save the `x` and `y` in a variable, so that in the `onAnimationEnd()` you move it not to a fix location.

Comment: Works!! but at new position of ImageView, it doesn't respond to any tap events, and also, if I click to its previous location, another instance of same imageview animates. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! but re-positioning in `onAnimationEnd()` causes imageview to flicker once. :-/

Comment: Before setting the LayoutParms you have to clear the animation (see above)

Comment: I think you should use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead only `LayoutParams` otherwise `setMargins()` not available.

Comment: Just to add things up, you don't need to set  margin manually after animation ends, if you set setFillAfter to true instead of false.

animation.setFillAfter(false);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70812265/4606860

Answer (score 10):

It is better to use `ObjectAnimator` which actually moves the ImageView to the new position.
E.g.:

```
ImageView splash;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float tx = event.getX();
    float ty = event.getY();

    int action = event.getAction();
    switch(action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            tx = event.getX();
            ty = event.getY();

            // findViewById(R.id.character).setX(tx-45);
            // findViewById(R.id.character).setY(ty-134);

            ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(splash, "x", tx-45);
            ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(splash, "y", ty-134);
            AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
            animSetXY.playTogether(animX, animY);
            animSetXY.start();

            break;
        default:
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Liked this one the best actually.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this code

```
imageView.animate().x(80).y(212).setDuration(300);
```

or

for soft animation you can use this library

https://github.com/wirecube/android_additive_animations

Answer (score 2):

In below code I am adding a image view in center on frame layout dynamically. After add I am increase scaling and set alpha to give zoom effect and after complete animation I am just translate my image view one position to another position.

Add image view on framelayout

```
    imgHeart = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
    imgHeart.setId(R.id.heartImage);
    imgHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.material_heart_fill_icon);
    imgHeart.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50, Gravity.CENTER));
    mainFrameLaout.addView(imgHeart);
```

Add animation on image view

```
       imgHeart.animate()
            .scaleXBy(6)
            .scaleYBy(6)
            .setDuration(700)
            .alpha(2)
            .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    imgHeart.animate()
                            .scaleXBy(-6f).scaleYBy(-6f)
                            .alpha(.1f)
                            .translationX((heigthAndWidth[0] / 2) - minusWidth)
                            .translationY(-((heigthAndWidth[1] / 2) - minusHeight))
                            .setDuration(1000)
                            .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                // remove image view from framlayout
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                                }
                            }).start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :)

```
 private void animeView(View imageView){

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int[] deltaX = {50};
        final int[] deltaRotation = {45};
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 imageView.animate().translationX(deltaX[0])
                                    .rotation(deltaRotation[0]).setDuration(1000) ;
                 deltaX[0] *=-1 ;
                 deltaRotation[0] *=-1 ;
                 handler.postDelayed(this , 1000);
             }
         },1000);

    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.