# Moving splash screen like facebook's splash screen

Tags: android, facebook, splash-screen

how can i do a splash screen like facebook's splash screen? 
In facebook's splash screen the facebook logo moves up and then apear the login view in the same view.
How can I do it?
I tried to draw aמ animation on existing view but i couldn't get the current canvas.

Comment: just take an image view and use translate animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an Image View for logo or any View you require.  Use translate animation , refer to this post [Move an ImageView to different position in Animated way in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144421/move-an-imageview-to-different-position-in-animated-way-in-android) or this [How to move an image from left to right in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689918/move-image-from-left-to-right-in-android)