# Android trying to move an imageview fluidly to where screen is tapped

Tags: android, touch, game-physics, ontouch

I am developing a simple game app for a class. Right now I am trying to implement the simple functionality of moving our character (an imageview) from wherever it currently resides to wherever the screen is tapped. I have this currently working, but there is no animation so the character just jumps from one position on the screen to where I tap the screen. 
Here's the code for that:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {    
    float tx = event.getX();
    float ty = event.getY();

    int action = event.getAction();
    switch(action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        tx = event.getX();
        ty = event.getY();

        findViewById(R.id.character).setX(tx-45);
        findViewById(R.id.character).setY(ty-134);
        break;
    default:
    }
    return true;
}
```

This code is in the GameActivity.java file, which I currently have controlling any sort of activity that occurs after you click "play game" and are taken to the game screen. 
I am trying to make the character (imageView) move from its current position to wherever the screen is tapped fluidly, so I tap the screen and the character moves over the course of some time period from its current location to the location where the tap occurred. Please help!

Comment: You can use TranslateAnimation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144421/move-an-imageview-to-different-position-in-animated-way-in-android

Comment: try my code ,, it's work good

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView splash ;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float tx = event.getX();
    float ty = event.getY();

    int action = event.getAction();
    switch(action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            tx = event.getX();
            ty = event.getY();

     //       findViewById(R.id.character).setX(tx-45);
      //      findViewById(R.id.character).setY(ty-134);

            ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(splash, "x", tx-45);
            ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(splash, "y", ty-134);
            AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
            animSetXY.playTogether(animX, animY);
            animSetXY.start();

            break;
        default:
    }
    return true;
}
```