# android animation move view to another view

Tags: android, android-layout, coordinates, android-animation

I have two views in different layouts I want to move one to another. What's wrong with my code? Y animation plays wrong. First view is located in fragment's layout, second in status bar

```
    ...
    int p1[] = new int[2];
    int p2[] = new int[2];
    viewOne.getLocationInWindow(p1);
    viewTwo.getLocationInWindow(p2);


    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet
            .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, "X", p1[0], p2[0] - p1[0]))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, "Y", p1[1], p2[1] - p1[1]))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale));
```

Comment: How does it play wrong?

Comment: @Whitney it should move to corner of the screen, but y does not grow

Comment: please see my answer, it's directly related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593484/2606290

Answer (score 28):

I have a another solution for you:(move viewOne to viewTwo)

```
 TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, viewTwo.getX()-viewOne.getX(),0 , viewTwo.getY()-viewOne.getY());
    animation.setRepeatMode(0);
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    viewOne.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: sorry, i tried this code but is not working how is supose to do.
i have an imageview and i want to move it to the other fixed image view

but in fact is moving my image some way on diagonal side to the up

Comment: *note:* views during initialization will return you position 0, try to perform this operation in `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable{}, 200);`

Comment: @KirillKarmazin alternatively to using a `Handler` you could also use the `onGlobalLayoutListener` on the `viewTreeObserver`, so that the above code is inside `viewTwo.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener { // Animation code here }`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private fun moveView(viewToBeMoved: View, targetView: View) {
    val targetX: Float =
        targetView.x + targetView.width / 2 - viewToBeMoved.width / 2
    val targetY: Float =
        targetView.y + targetView.height / 2 - viewToBeMoved.height / 2

    viewToBeMoved.animate()
        .x(targetX)
        .y(targetY)
        .setDuration(2000)
        .withEndAction {
            targetView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        .start()
}
```