# Animate CircledImageView position

Tags: android

I have a `CircledImageView` which I'm using in my `ViewPager`. I want when I switch the tab on the `ViewPager` to animate the position of the `CircledImageView` to go to the bottom (currently is in the middle). Is this possible?
My CircledImageView code:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.CircledImageView
        android:id="@+id/moreIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/backDropPath"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_36dp"
        app:circle_color="@color/detailsMoreIconBackground"
        app:circle_radius="28dp" />
```

Comment: [Try](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11144574) this

Comment: Post solution below. So that it will help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user2286580 said. I had to create two methods and two listeners one for up direction and one for down direction:

```
    public void createDownAnimation() {
    downAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 50, 0, 100);
    downAnimation.setDuration(500);
    downAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
    downAnimation.setAnimationListener(new DownAnimationListener());
}
```

And the listener:

```
    private class DownAnimationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        moreIcon.clearAnimation();
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
        lp.setMargins(50, 100, 0, 0);
        moreIcon.setLayoutParams(lp);
        moreIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

}
```

For the up direction it's similar.