# How can I swap the position of two or more images?

Tags: android, image

How can I change the position of these ImageViews by giving them the position of another? (Swapping them around  in Slow Motion)

```
blue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageB);
red = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageR);
Green = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageG);
int x = blue.getLeft();
int y = blue.getTop();

int x1 = red.getLeft();
int y1 = red.getTop();

int x2 = Green.getLeft();
int y2 = Green.getTop();


Green.setLeft(x);
Green.setTop(y);

blue.setLeft(x1);
blue.setTop(y1);

red.setLeft(x2);
red.setTop(y2);`
```

Comment: Why you don't keep the ImageViews at their position and switch their background?

Comment: I want to give them some animation ... by moving  them slowly

Comment: Attempted to make this more understandable, it's certainly a riddle. I do recommend mentioning what the actual problem your having is, for example posting relevant crash logs or expected vs reality in terms of outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

In android there is a difference between layout and animations. To animate images use **TranslateAnimation**, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144421/move-an-imageview-to-different-position-in-animated-way-in-android).

How ever in the end of the animation, your images will return to their original position as the layout did not changed. So you need to set a callback to when animation is finished and change your images background so the layout will mach the animation.

Also there are several ways to achieve this, read more about animations [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html).